# Enemies All Spawning In Same Place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want some enemies to spawn in 4 different locations for a survival-type game. The problem is, they all spawn in the same place. Why is this? This is in Unity by the way.

C# script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
public int spawnHere = 0;
public int spawnTimer = 0;
public int spawnRate = 1;
public Transform spawner1;
public Transform spawner2; 
public Transform spawner3;
public Transform spawner4;
public GameObject melee1;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {



}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    spawnTimer = spawnTimer + spawnRate;
    spawnHere = Random.Range (1, 5);
    if(spawnTimer >= 120) {
        if(spawnHere == 1) {
            Instantiate (melee1, spawner1);
}
        if(spawnHere == 2) {
            Instantiate (melee1, spawner2);
        }
        if(spawnHere == 3) {
            Instantiate (melee1, spawner3);
        }
        if(spawnHere == 4) {
            Instantiate (melee1, spawner3);
        }
        spawnTimer = 0;

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Probably not your problem, but the last case should result in `Instantiate (melee1, spawner4);` shouldn't it? Not `Instantiate (melee1, spawner3);`?

Comment: Oh, yes, but as you said that is not the problem.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `spawnHere` to see what it's giving?

Comment: Yes. They even are children of their spawners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you connected the spawners correctly in the UI?

Watch this: [Unity - Survival Shooter - Spawning Enemies](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/more-enemies?playlist=17144)

This worked pretty good for my project.

You should also use Time.deltaTime for timing the spawns. Not every system outputs the same amount of frames / second.

[Unity - docs - Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

BTW:

> Random.rand(min, max)

[Unity - docs - Random.Rand](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)
 includes max as a possible value.

Comment: btw `UnityEngine.Random.Range (1, 5);` does not include `5` as a possible value.